# VsBrush doesn't work in WPF ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, contenttemplate

*tl;dr*

## Problem description

*First of all, I'm new to WPF and I have little to now idea what I'm doing...*

I'm developing **a Visual Studio 2013 Extension in which I create a custom Tool Window**. Since the WPF controls don't **inherit themes from parent (i.e. Visual Studio main window)**, you have to to it manually.

I read that I should use the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsBrushes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsbrushes(v=vs.120).aspx) or the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.EnvironmentColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.environmentcolors.aspx) classes as they define the Visual Studio shell theme specific constants. ([See example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913208/colors-in-visual-studio-extension)) This works all fine as long as I use this within a `Style` tag.

However, Microsoft's [Menu and MenuItem ControlTemplate Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296(v=vs.110).aspx) explains how to do a proper **MenyItem template using `<ContentTemplate>`**.
The problem is, that neither the VsBrush nor the EnvironmentColors don't work within the `<ContentTemplate>`. Either there is a **generic exception** complaining when I set the color for `<GradintStop>` (no details, what the problem is), **or the UI just hangs**, doesn't even load. In this later case when I break the application, I always en up in `MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMessageW()` function.

### Questions

1. Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and why I can't use the `VsBrushes` and `EnvironmentColors` classes in my `<ContentTemplate>`?
2. How can I properly style my Visual Studio Extension using the suggested `<ContentTemplate>` format?

### Attempts To Solve The Issue

1. I checked in the constructor of the whole package, that the color constants of the `VsBrushes` class can be fetched. Only after the constructor does the UI hang, so the `VsBrushes` values must be initialized by the time the XAML is processed.
2. As pointed out above, without the use of `<ControlTemplate>` the constants can be used.
3. Investigated the exception: it was thrown when the parser tried to interpret the Color property of the `<GradientStop>` tag. No explanation what exactly failed. (After a while -- as the code changed a bit -- the exception ceased and the UI hang started.)
4. If I change the `LinearGradientBrush` to `SolidColorBrush` the problem still persists (of course the exception is slightly different this time): 'Set property 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.Color' threw an exception.
5. The problem is not `<MenuItem>` specific. It can be reproduced with `<Button>` and I guess with any arbitrary WPF control.

### Source

*Here's the code I use for defining my style for MenuItems:*

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vsShell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0"
                    xmlns:vsUI="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0">
    <Color x:Key="MyColor">#FFFFFF00</Color>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStopCollection>
                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MyColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderColorKey}}" Offset="0.1" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF00FF00" Offset="0.5" />
                                        <!-- The following 3 do not work -->
                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.AccentBorderBrushKey}}" Offset="0.8" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsShell:VsBrushes.AccentBorderKey}}" Offset="0.8" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource VsBrush.AccentBorder}" Offset="1.0" />
                                    </GradientStopCollection>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0.5" StartPoint="1,0.5">
                                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

### Call Stack

*This is where the process "hangs":*

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMessageW(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWnd, int uMsgFilterMin, int uMsgFilterMax) Line 566  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.GetMessage(ref System.Windows.Interop.MSG msg, System.IntPtr hwnd, int minMessage, int maxMessage) Line 391 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) Line 979  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) Line 961  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() Line 1059 C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0.dll!Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.BackgroundDispatcher.ThreadProc(object arg)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(object obj)  Unknown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resolution

All these following 3 lines cause compilation error, because **the compiler expects a `Color` but I gave it a `Brush` instead.**

```
<GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.AccentBorderBrushKey}}" Offset="0.8" />
<GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsShell:VsBrushes.AccentBorderKey}}" Offset="0.8" />
<GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource VsBrush.AccentBorder}" Offset="1.0" />
```

**I should have use `<GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsUI:EnvironmentColors.AccentBorderColorKey}}" Offset="0.8" />` instead.** (Notice that I use AccentBorderColorKey instead of AccentBorderBrushKey.)

XAML is parsing string and tries to interpret that which leads to a simple fact: XAML is typeless (everything is a string). Since the error message (*'Set property 'System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush.Color' threw an exception.*) is not really talkative, it doesn't really help you understand what you did wrong.

### Lesson learned

Try to check the type manually if the compiler doesn't do it for you (or doesn't tell you that it is what causes the problem.)