# How do I handle dark themes with Visual Studio extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have written an extension for Visual Studio.  Unfortunately when a user has a dark theme the colour is a jarring white and light blue.

How do I set the colour of a ListView in an extension to be relative the the theme?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913208/colors-in-visual-studio-extension

Comment: Hi Stefan, any update for this issue? Just want to clarify if Sergey's answer in another link helps to resolve your issue :)

Comment: Hi, I think I kept getting compilation errors when trying it as certain bits of data were not available for me.  I will check again and see what state the ext is in (I have not used it for months)